# Disable in renders not working

Tags: rendering, instances

I have an issue with instancing to the scene and I don't understand why that is happening. In my file, I Instance to Scene multiple collections for them to appear and disappear at specific times. But in my final renders, the collections still appear. *How would I go around fixing that?*
[image]

Comment: green means: it is keyframed. So you should check whether it is rendered also on that frames, where camera is off.

Comment: it is keyframed from frame 1 and is meant to turn on only at 53. The issue persists on frame 1 (when the keyframe is yellow)

Answer (score 2):

I have found the answer, pretty simple actually. The problem was that the 'instance to scene' was existing at the same time as the collection, so all you have to do is uncheck the collection as shown in the image.
[image]